# Why is collapsible not working for the dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am retrieving the data(question) from the database and setting that value to the button.

When I tried to click on the button it should expand the "answer" to that question but it's not happening. I have completely designed rows in the script itself.

I have created a div in HTML and trying to add the rows dynamically to that div in script.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div id="questions">
    </div> 
 </div>


 <script>
   var store;
   var store_count = 0;
   var store_row = document.createElement("div");

    db.collection("FAQs").orderBy("Priority","asc").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                var qid = doc.id;
                var docRef = db.collection("PopopFAQs").doc(qid);
                docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                        store_count++;
                        store = document.createElement("div");
                        store.setAttribute("class", "card");
                        store.setAttribute("id", qid); 
                        if(store_count == 1) {
                            store.innerHTML = `<div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-link no-wrap collapsed btn-faqs" type="button"
                                                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#`+ doc.data().Priority +`"
                                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> `+ doc.data().Question +`
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="`+ doc.data().Priority +`" class="collapse show"
                                                aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                                <div class="card-body">`+ doc.data().Answer +`
                                                </div>
                                            </div>`;
                        }
                        else {
                            store.innerHTML = `<div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-link no-wrap collapsed btn-faqs" type="button"
                                                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#`+ doc.data().Priority +`"
                                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> `+ doc.data().Question +`
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="`+ doc.data().Priority +`" class="collapse"
                                                aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                                <div class="card-body">`+ doc.data().Answer +`
                                                </div>
                                            </div>`;
                        }


                        store_row.append(store);
                        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = store_row.innerHTML;
                    } else {
                        console.log("No such document!");
                    }
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                });
            });

        });
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var content = this.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                  content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Db operation callback runs async. So when you try to add them eventhandlers they are not in the DOM. You need to do those operations after your callback. You can chain another `then` to achieve that.

Comment: @Eldar -I did not get u. Can u please tell me more clearly?

Comment: I mean this : `db....get().then(dbCallback).then(domManagementCallback)`

Comment: Can you share your final html that is getting rendered?

Comment: @Eldar - Do I need to add then for the main query?

Comment: If you mean `getElementsByClassName("accordion")` with the main query yes. You should move from starting that line into then.